# Zend Framework Add Route

Tags: php, zend-framework

I need to Add the route to Zend Framwork Application.

I want to display All the Posts from the database where catagory = the controller name

```
domain.com/action 
domian.com/drama
domain.com/thriller
```

How can i do this ? I gone through the ZF Routes Documentation. But found No Solution.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to do this, you will have to put something like this in your application.ini

```
resources.router.routes.category.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.category.route = ":category"
resources.router.routes.category.defaults.module = "default"
resources.router.routes.category.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.category.defaults.action = "index"
```

This way, everything that didn't match as a valid controller will be directed as category parameter in index controller index action. Keep in mind to handle invalid category names and trigger 404.

Also, here's a good article about [tricks and tips in application.ini](http://www.iostream.eu/zend-framework-application-ini-cheat-sheet/)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using addRoute() method in the bootstrap.php file

```
// Retrieve the front controller from the bootstrap registry
$FrontController = $this->getResource('FrontController');
$router = $FrontController->getRouter();

$router->addRoute('genre', 
                  new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':genre',array( 'controller' => 'index' , 'action' => 'index'  )) );
```

To get the Genre in the Controller

```
echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('genre')
```